# Database query gives no error either no result?

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello my code does not give any error but not result of a name thats in db ?
the code is the following for the form to process the data the user inputs to the php file.
HTML User input code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="search.php">
 <input type="text" name="search">
 <input type="submit">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Php code:

```
     <?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","acksocial");

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
printf("Connection failed:%s \n",mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
$table = 'acksearch';

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name = $name", MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
while($row = $result->fetcssh_object())
    {

// $row is an associative array

// Do something here

echo "Name: ".$row['name'];

echo " country: ".$row['country'];

}
}
$db->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes the string, but doesn't quote it, so your query has a syntax error.

Replace it with:

```
"... WHERE name = '$name'"...
```

Please check for *and report* (or log, or whatever) errors when using database functions.

Comment: Also MySQLi does not generate errors like MySql. If you want to see the errors you need to grab them. see mysqli_error mysqli_errno.